# Can a deadlock in a databases affect other databases or hung entire server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, deadlock

This sounds pretty strange, but there is ocurring in a databases of a bunch we've got in a server, we can tell by the output on the log, but this seems to be affecting another databases, since the systems hungs when the deadlock occur.

We've identified the objects involved in the deadlock event, but none lives in the databases from the system we are using.

I still need to look at the procedure bodies, but is this possible? processes from other databases entering in deadlock and hunging the entire server or other databases?

Comment: Do the hung databases recover once the dump of the lock is recorded/resolved?  I've seen that happen on ORACLE databases. it's not that the deadlock locks everything, it's just that the processor goes to 100% and the file IO is so intensive, there's no bandwidth for the other processes.  It's like the deadlock is first in line and it can't multi task until it's done. (so yes I've seen it happen)

Comment: Thanks @xQbert indeed the server cat eat up cpu and i/o resources, could be a cause. and yes it gets resolved after the lock is resolved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A deadlock is not a fatal event in MS Sql Server (unlike, eg., in code). This is because Sql Server will periodically scan for deadlocks, and then pick one of the of the processes to kill. That's when you get the log messages.

Absent a Sql Server bug (which I've never encountered), I'd think it's more likely that the order is reversed - the hung server/database prevents normal execution of queries, resulting in deadlocks as procedures take longer to execute.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this happen when two processes that are in a deadlock also have objects locked in TempDB.

The locked objects in tempdb then stop other processes from being able to create objects and thus hang.

This was an issue on older versions of SQL Server (2000), but I can't recall seeing it on more recent version.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible. if your server can't react to any interupt it can't execute other requests (correctly).